# AutoHotKey - Replace Multiple Lines in File

Tags: autohotkey

I'm fairly new to AutoHotkey, and using it to pull in an API JSON file from a URL to a file. I've figured how to replace single-line text to replace an invalid JSON object, but am now trying to find a pattern within the file and ADD two additional lines before parsing the file into SQL table.

Currently looking for the following multi-line pattern:

```
"AAA": x.xx,   *Note: x.xx is a decimal number that can change per record.*
}
```

Need to add the following two lines after the first line:

```
"BBB" {
  "CCC": NULL
```

Final result needs to be:

```
"AAA": x.xx,
"BBB": {
  "CCC": NULL
}
```

Comment: Does the api actually serve a broken json like that? Could you show an actual example of a json response from the api?

Comment: @0x464e Sorry, new to stackoverflow too, trying to insert a sample but it's not formatting correctly.

Comment: @0x464e Here's a excerpt from the json file. I've taken some objects out. Still trying to get use to stackoverflow.    {"dt":1627322400,"temp":88.63,"feels_like":94.64,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0},{"dt":1627326000,"temp":88.38,"feels_like":93.7,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"pop":0.4,"rain":{"r1h":0.13}},{"dt":1627329600,"temp":87.71,"feels_like":92.84,"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],"pop":0.08},

Comment: I was more wondering that if the json the website serves is actually invalidly formatted (like your question seems to suggest), and you're trying to fix it, or if the json is actually fine. If it's fine, you don't need to worry about matching a pattern, you can just load the json and add the field(s) you want.

Comment: I feel that the JSON response is valid, perhaps you're saving it incorrectly? AHK can read HTTP response directly.

Answer (score 0):

When editing a JSON file, there are much better ways to do this. However, if you just want to insert some lines you can do it like so:

```
oldFile := "original_file.json"
newFile := "edited_file.json"

insertText =
(
"BBB" {
  "CCC": NULL
)

Loop, Read, % oldFile, % newFile
{
    FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n
    
    ; If last written line is a match, add new lines
    if RegExMatch(A_LoopReadLine, """AAA"": \d+.\d+,")
    {    
        FileAppend, %insertText%`n
    }
}
```